# Import File Preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, ofx

I have this form which import transactions of the user. I enhance the form where user can preview the list of transactions they will be importing to their account.

Sample:

[image]

The above sample preview is for the QIF file format which I successfully done.

Now I'm trying to preview the OFX file format and I'm having difficulty to arrange it in a table and get the exact value.

Here are my codes:

```
<input type="file" name="transactions" id="id_transactions">

<div style="display:none;width:335px;" id="preview-box">
    <h4 class="thin" class="black">Import Preview</h4>

    <table class="simple-table responsive-table footable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="10%"><small class="black">Date</small></th>
                <th scope="col" width="10%"><small class="black">Amount</small></th>
                <th scope="col" width="20%"><small class="black">Payee</small></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="scrollable" style="height:100px">
        <table class="simple-table responsive-table footable">
            <tbody id="preview-table"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div><br/>
</div> 

<script>
    $('#id_transactions').change(function() {
        var upload = document.getElementById('id_transactions')
        var files = upload.files
        if (files != undefined) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var extension = upload.value.split('.').pop().toLowerCase()
                var lineSplit = e.target.result.split("\n");
                var payee = ''
                var date
                var amount
                var content = "";
                var content1 = "";
                var content2 = "";

                if(extension == "qif"){
                    // for qif preview
                }else if(extension == "ofx"){
                    $('#preview-box').show(500)

                    for(var i = 1; i < lineSplit.length; i++) {
                        //I'm stuck here....
                    }
                }

                $('#preview-table').html(content);
            };
            reader.readAsText(files.item(0));
        }
    });
</script>
```

**sample.ofx**

```
 OFXHEADER:100
DATA:OFXSGML
VERSION:103
SECURITY:NONE
ENCODING:USASCII
CHARSET:1252
COMPRESSION:NONE
OLDFILEUID:NONE
NEWFILEUID:NONE

<OFX>
  <SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
    <SONRS>
      <STATUS>
        <CODE>0
        <SEVERITY>INFO
      </STATUS>
      <DTSERVER>20071015021529.000[-8:PST]
      <LANGUAGE>ENG
      <DTACCTUP>19900101000000
      <FI>
        <ORG>MYBANK
        <FID>01234
      </FI>
    </SONRS>
  </SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
  <BANKMSGSRSV1>
      <STMTTRNRS>
        <TRNUID>23382938
        <STATUS>
          <CODE>0
          <SEVERITY>INFO
        </STATUS>
        <STMTRS>
          <CURDEF>USD
          <BANKACCTFROM>
            <BANKID>987654321
            <ACCTID>098-121
            <ACCTTYPE>SAVINGS
          </BANKACCTFROM>
          <BANKTRANLIST>
            <DTSTART>20070101
            <DTEND>20071015
            <STMTTRN>
              <TRNTYPE>CREDIT
              <DTPOSTED>20070315
              <DTUSER>20070315
              <TRNAMT>200.00
              <FITID>980315001
              <NAME>DEPOSIT
              <MEMO>automatic deposit
            </STMTTRN>
            <STMTTRN>
              <TRNTYPE>CREDIT
              <DTPOSTED>20070329
              <DTUSER>20070329
              <TRNAMT>150.00
              <FITID>980310001
              <NAME>TRANSFER
              <MEMO>Transfer from checking
            </STMTTRN>
            <STMTTRN>
              <TRNTYPE>PAYMENT
              <DTPOSTED>20070709
              <DTUSER>20070709
              <TRNAMT>-100.00
              <FITID>980309001
                <CHECKNUM>1025
              <NAME>John Hancock
            </STMTTRN>
          </BANKTRANLIST>
          <LEDGERBAL>
            <BALAMT>5250.00
            <DTASOF>20071015021529.000[-8:PST]
          </LEDGERBAL>
          <AVAILBAL>
            <BALAMT>5250.00
            <DTASOF>20071015021529.000[-8:PST]
          </AVAILBAL>
        </STMTRS>
      </STMTTRNRS>
  </BANKMSGSRSV1>
</OFX>
```

Anyone who already done this?

**UPDATE:**

Output:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for an OFX parser, by chance?

Comment: @MaxArt No, I already read this file using python. What I really need is using javascript or jquery in reading this file for preview.

Comment: Ok, but you need a parser anyway if you want to display its content in a decent form. Or do you want to display that as a wall of text?

Comment: @MaxArt I think not, in my codes I already using the table. I successfully read the QIF file format which I arrange it in the table without using parser or anything (it's pure javascript). I believe this is possible in javascript or jquery.

Comment: Yes, with a parser. In fact, a Javascript parser. To read a QIF file you used a Javascript parser too. So, do you need one for OFX files or not? What's your main problem here, reading the file the user selected or displaying its content in a table? Or both?

Answer (score 2):

You know what, this OFX file format looks a lot like an XML in the second part, with an empty line separating the two parts (correct me if I'm wrong, I don't know this format).

Inside the `onload` event listener, try something like this:

```
var ofxParts = e.result.split("\r?\n\r?\n"), ofxHeaders, ofxDocument;

ofxHeaders = JSON.parse("{"
    + ofxParts[0].replace(/(\w+) *: *(\w*)/g, "\"$1\": \"$2\"")
        .replace(/\r?\n/g, ", ") + "}");

ofxDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(ofxParts[1]
        .replace(/<(\w+)>(?!\n|\r\n)(.*)/g, "<$1>$2</$1>"));
```

Now you should have the OFX headers in a useful Javascript object like this:

```
ofxHeaders = {
    "OFXHEADER": "100",
    "DATA": "OFXSGML",
    "VERSION": "103",
    "SECURITY": "NONE",
    "ENCODING": "USASCII",
    "CHARSET": "1252",
    "COMPRESSION": "NONE",
    "OLDFILEUID": "NONE",
    "NEWFILEUID": "NONE"
};
```

and you can crawl and select your OFX document with `document.evaluate` like any other XML.

This should all be available as far as you're using `FileReader`. Except IE10, which doesn't support `document.evaluate`. You'll have to create an `ActiveXObject` and use `loadXML` if you want to use XPath.

Or you can just use jQuery:

```
var $ofx = $.parseXML(ofxParts[1].replace(/<(\w+)>(?!\n|\r\n)(.*)/g, "<$1>$2</$1>"));
```

**Edit**: You can now create the rows of the table in this kind of way:

```
var $xfers = $ofx.find("STMTTRN");

content = $xfers.map(function(xf) {
    var $xf = $(xf), date = $xf.find("DTPOSTED").text();
    return "<tr><td>" + date.substring(4, 6) + "/" + date.substring(6)
        + "/" + date.substring(0, 4) + "<td></td>" + $xf.find("NAME").text()
        + "</td><td>" + $xf.find("TRNAMT").text() + "</td></tr>";
}).join("");
```

Comment: I update my question for the output. Like I said I didn't use parser. I just simply use `if and else statement` but if you want to use that parser OK I will give it a try. I want `reading the file the user selected and displaying its content in a table`. Yes this like XML that's why I'm having difficulty in getting the output.

Comment: @catherine You see, even if you say "I'm just using `if` and `else`", what you're doing there is a parsing job. You actually wrote your own *parser*. I tried to make you one in this answers. So, does it work or do I have to tweak it a bit?

Comment: the ofxheader is not included in the output. See the output in my question. If you can solve this I will give you bounty :). And it must be arrange in table.

Comment: @catherine Ok, I added a snippet that puts the data in a table. Note that you haven't given any info about what data you want, and how you want them to be displayed. My answers is a shot in the dark. Feel free to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: How can I use this in the table? I mean in my original codes. Looks like your answer is for the best start. I can picture the flow now.

Comment: @catherine I'm not sure I understood what you mean with 'use this in the table'. I think my answer pretty much fulfills your question. I see you defined that `content` variable, so I used it in the snippet.